# How to use axios to get all response data when there are multiple pages?

Tags: node.js, get, axios

I have a URL like `https://abc123/api/records` that gives me:

```
{"page":1,"per_page":10,"total":99,"total_pages":10,"data":[object1, object2, object3,...]}
```

```
axios.get("https://abc123.com/api/records?&page=2")
  .then(response => console.log(response.data))
```

Will then give me something like

```
{"page":2,"per_page":10,"total":99,"total_pages":10,"data":[object1, object2, object3,...]}
```

I want to access all the objects in "data" from all 10 pages. How would I do that using nodeJS and axios?

Comment: Loop until the `page` you're currently getting is the same as the `total_pages`? What have you tried so far, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a loop such as [do ... while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) to download each page of data. We'll stop downloading once we have retrieved the last page of data.

We set the page parameter using the params object, starting with page 1.

```
const axios = require("axios");

// Replace with the appropriate url.
const url = "https://abc123.com/api/records"

async function downloadRecords() {

    let records = [];
    let page = 0;
    let totalPages = 0;

    do {
        let { data: response }  = await axios.get(url, { params: { page: ++page } });
        totalPages = response.total_pages;
        console.log(`downloadRecords: page ${page} of ${totalPages} downloaded...`);
        records = records.concat(response.data);
        console.log("records.length:", records.length);
    } while (page < totalPages)

    console.log("downloadRecords: download complete.")
}

downloadRecords();
```